# Sharing Google sheets using addEditor

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am making a spreadsheet for people to submit information and when they submit the information on the entry sheet, the data is copied to a new sheet and then cleared from the entry sheet so that it is ready for another entry. When the new sheet is created, it is renamed and then shared with me so that I can view each sheet that people send in. Right now my script isn't working and I am not receiving the new sheets when they are made.

```
function Copy() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:J30'); 
 var strange = ss.getRange('A2:J30');
 var data = range.getValues();
 sss.appendRow(data[0]);
 strange.clear();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.create('New Entry'); 
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); 
 var r = ts.getRange('A2:A3');
 r.getA1Notation() == 'A2';
 tss.setName(r.getValue());
 tss.addEditor("john.doe@gmail.com");
}
```

Comment: There are few unwanted lines but the New Entry gets created, you can check under the recent section of the Google Drive

Comment: I need the sheet to share with other people specifically using the addEditor at the bottom of the code. When the code executes, the sheets are not being shared, they are only visible to the user.

Comment: Question for you, are you trying to pass in new editors to the sheet or does this live under a shared folder where anyone who is a member of the folder automatically receives the access to the new sheet.  That said if you need multiple editors not members of a folder,  just change your tss.addEditor to addEditors(arrayofEmails) and pass in the array of email addresses and that will get you what you need.  If this is what you are trying to do i can put a better reference down.